# Which preposition goes with the word "altar"?

Tags: prepositions, sentence, word-usage

I am getting contradictory usages of the word *altar* :

1. Sacrificed his family life on the altar of career advancement([Source:Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/altar))
2. You probably aren't going to like the solution, but the goal right now is not to get the perfect answer but to pass the test. We'll make our sacrifice at the altar of truth and beauty later.([Source : A book by Kent Beck on TDD](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321146530)

So should the usage be like *on the altar* OR *at the altar*?

Comment: Both are dandy.

Comment: By and large, you perform a sacrifice *at* an altar, but the offering/victim is sacrificed *on* the altar.

Comment: You lead an interesting life, StoneyB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are not contradictory, but complementary.

The thing that is being sacrificed goes **on** the altar.  (In sentence one, "his family life" is being sacrificed.)

The person doing the sacrificing stands **at** the altar.  (In sentence two, "We" are making our (unspecified) sacrifice to the gods of truth and beauty.)